# What is meaning of "bulleted" in "A bulleted list of learning objectives provides you with the opportunity to preview what will be presented in **"

Tags: meaning

The original text is:

> A bulleted list of learning objectives provides
> you with the opportunity to preview what will
> be presented in the upcoming section.

I can find nothing at [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english-chinese-simplified/?q=bulleted) and [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/american_english/?q=bulleted).

So what is meaning of "bulleted" in "A bulleted list of learning objectives provides
you with the opportunity to preview what will
be presented in the upcoming section." Thank you.

Comment: It just means a list where each item in the list is preceded by a bullet point.  A 'bullet point' is a large round dot that is commonly indented one tab's worth from the text preceding it.  A bulleted list is an alternative to (for example) a numbered list:  the bullet points take the place of 1), 2), 3) etc.

Comment: A Google images search for "bulleted list example" should give you a nice sampling of how this can look

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Thank you for your explain, but why doesn't the dictionary have this definition?

Comment: Sometimes, just searching for the term you want to find out about, followed by something like 'meaning' or 'definition,' gives you better results than searching within a given dictionary.

Comment: I just tried searching "bulleted list definition" and this came up close to the top of the results: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/bullet-list/

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Thank you for your method to find out word's 'meaning' or 'definition.

Comment: Also, dictionaries can't provide entries for every possible part of speech.  *Bulleted* looks like the past participle of *bullet*.  And what do we find if we look up *bullet*?  ["a large dot placed in printed matter to call attention to a particular passage"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bullet)

Comment: @stangdon I see "a large dot placed in printed matter to call attention to a particular passage" at number 2's b in link of your comment.   And at here, why use the past participle of bullet? Thank you.

Comment: @Tom That's a very good question!  The past participle is how we make a verb into an adjective.  For example, if "they steal the books", the books are "*stolen* books".  If "they defeat the enemy", the enemy is "a *defeated* enemy."  The author put bullets on the list, so the author *bulleted* the list, and it is a *bulleted* list.

Comment: @stangdon I know, thank you for your explanation.